# Проблема окружения при администрировани macos средствами salt

Tags: mac, saltstack

У меня есть несколько десятков компьютеров mac, на которые есть задача установить различный софт (putty, git, draw-io, mosquitto), а, а также урезать права юзера (например, чтобы user не мог сам скачивать софт). Я установил вручную saltstack на каждый из этих компьютеров, затем запустил salt master и принял все ключи. Далее я написал несколько .sls файлов, чтобы установить по, однако я каждый раз получаю ошибку:

```
     ID: homebrew
        Function: pkg.installed
          Result: False
         Comment: Unable to run command '['brew', '--prefix']' with the context '{'cwd':
 '/var/root', 'shell': False, 'env': {'OLDPWD': '/', 'PATH': '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin',
 'PWD': '/opt/salt', 'XPC_FLAGS': '0x0', 'XPC_SERVICE_NAME': '0', 'SHLVL': '0', 'LC_CTYPE': 'C',
 'SSL_CERT_DIR': '/private/etc/ssl/certs', 'SSL_CERT_FILE': '/private/etc/ssl/cert.pem',
 'LC_NUMERIC': 'C', 'LC_TIME': 'C', 'LC_COLLATE': 'C', 'LC_MONETARY': 'C', 'LC_MESSAGES': 'C',
 'LC_PAPER': 'C', 'LC_NAME': 'C', 'LC_ADDRESS': 'C', 'LC_TELEPHONE': 'C', 'LC_MEASUREMENT': 'C',
 'LC_IDENTIFICATION': 'C', 'LANGUAGE': 'C'}, 'stdin': None, 'stdout': -1, 'stderr': -2,
 'with_communicate': True, 'timeout': None, 'bg': False, 'close_fds': True}',
 reason: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'brew'
         Started: 17:51:13.166312
        Duration: 15.798 ms
         Changes:
    
              ID: putty
        Function: pkg.installed
          Result: False
         Comment: One or more requisite failed: mac.software.putty.homebrew
         Started: 17:51:13.182820
        Duration: 0.003 ms
         Changes:
    
    Summary for MAC-08-mac.local
```

Испробовал множество вариантов устранения ошибки. Скачивал brew отдельным файлом и пытался его установить перед тем, как устанавливаю putty. Пробовал также изменять в /etc/salt/minion переменную sudo_user, а также просто user, ибо как мне тогда казалось ошибка была в brew из под рута. Также пробовал расширение для brew "Homebrew Cask", но ошибка всегда одна и та же. Пробовал один в один реализовать пример с официальной документации https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/tutorials/walkthrough_macosx.html . Но ошибка не изменилась. Нашел тему на форуме narkive.com, где говорили, что во всем виновата переменная среды HOME. Собственно на этом я поиски и прекратил, т.к. ресурсы закончились. Поэтому очень хочу узнать у профессиональных сисадминов или более осведомленных людей в чем дело и как можно это исправить (не судите строго, я впервые занимаюсь системным администрированием и только учусь). На всякий случай приложу команду, которой запускаю скрипт:

salt 'MAC-08-mac.local' state.highstate saltenv=development

Сам нахожусь под рутом (пробовал и без рута с sudo, но ничего не поменялось). Запускаю скрипт из директории
/opt/salt/development/mac/software. в software лежат скрипты, такие как putty.sls, visual-studio-code.sls... А запускается файл software-mac.sls, который лежит в /opt/salt/development/mac. В нем через инклюд перечислены файлы, которые запускаются (попытался повторить архитектуру из книги "Salt Cookbook" Aniban Saha). Как возможный вариант ошибки покажу также putty.sls:

```
putty:
  pkg.installed:
    - require:
      - pkg: homebrew
```

есть также файл homebrew.sls:

```
homebrew:
  pkg.installed
```

И разумеется в /opt/salt/development/mac/software-mac.sls все крайне просто:

```
include:
#soft
  - software.homebrew
  - software.putty
```

Буду крайне благодарен любой информации по теме и ссылкам на литературу, которая может продвинуть в данном вопросе